# Runtime error in ideal Coefficient ring of LHS must be a field

Tags: magma-ca

I am trying the following code in magma

```
   z:=Integers();
   P<x>:=PolynomialRing(z);
   ideal<P|x>;
```

I tried also :

```
 z:=GR(2,2,1);
 P<x>:=PolynomialRing(z);
 ideal<P|x>;
```

both are shown the same erreur "Runtime error in ideal< ... >: Coefficient ring of LHS must be a field"
Im trying to construct an ideal of Z[x]

Comment: I'm having the same problem...

Comment: @Dane, did you solve this issue?

Comment: unfortunately no